# How can I compute logarithm when comparison is undecidable?

Tags: algorithms, computability, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

In Haskell, I have the following datatypes that encodes arbitrary real numbers and arbitrary complex numbers, respectively:

```
newtype ArbReal = ArbReal {approximate :: Word -> Integer}
data ArbComplex = ArbReal :+ ArbReal
```

For the `ArbReal` type, the `ArbReal` constructor labels a function that, when fed an integer $n$, computes the encoded real number to $n$ decimal digits below the decimal point, rounded. For example, when `ArbReal f = pi`, `f 0` = 3, `f 1` = 31, `f 2` = 314, and so on.

Note that there is no guarantee to the direction of rounding. Given `ArbReal g = 0.5`, `g 0` can be either 0 or 1. This is inevitable, for if there were, an interval would be decidable.

`ArbComplex` encodes a complex number by specifying its real part and imaginary part.

I've successfully implemented addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division on both types. Division by 0 falls in an infinite loop, though.

I also implemented nth root function of real numbers, square root function of complex numbers (where branch cut doesn't exist, hence multivalued), and $\pi$.

Now it's time to implement natural logarithm (on complex numbers, without a branch cut). And that's where a problem emerged. I was implementing the algorithm (namely, AGM iteration) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3412.pdf), but:

> Finally, if $0< x <1$, we may use $\log(x) =−\log(1/x)$, where $\log(1/x)$ is computed as above.

This paragraph forces a comparison, which is undecidable. So it's impossible to implement the algorithm directly. Indeed, in my current version of implementation, $\log 1$ falls in an infinite loop.

Is there a tweak on the algorithm that makes the algorithm computable? Or must I implement a completely different algorithm?

Comment: To everyone reading this question: It turns out this is a wrong way of implementing the reals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though absolute comparisons may not converge, you should be able to narrow the argument into at least one of several partially overlapping ranges, such that you have a technique that works in that range.

For example, you should be able to tell that $x$ definitely falls into at least one of the ranges $A = \left(0,\frac{3}{4}\right]$, $B = \left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right]$, or $C = \left[\frac{5}{4},\infty\right)$ with little difficulty. Use AGM if it's in $C$, the transformation if it's in $A$, and if it's in $B$, use this transformation:

$$\log (x) = \log (2x) - \log 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Logarithm is undefined for x<0 and -infinity when x=0, that’s something you have to handle somehow. For the test x < 1: whatever approximation you use for x >= 1 will most likely work for x > 0.9999. You don’t need to decide if x < 1, just if x is small enough. For x = 0.99995 either decision will work.